# Change background color when user logs in and out

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Site could be found at http://trade.edicy.co/

Currently, it has the most basic implementation of the FB log-in button that automatically turns into a log out button after authentication. Now I want the background to change color once the user logs-in and revert back after the user logs-out.

Also is it possible to move the position and size of the Facebook picture far from the log-in button after log-in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the `auth.statusChange` event via the `FB.Event.subscribe` function of the JS SDK. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/#login-logout for a description. Additionally, you can have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

For example

```
var loginCallback= function(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire

      document.body.style.background = "red";

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
    } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        document.body.style.background = "green";
    }

}

// In your onload handler add this call
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', loginCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I ask where do I put these in the code?  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   //<--document.body.style.background = "red"; This here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your app seems not correctly set up, at least I get an error message once I try to login!

Comment: I manage to log-in and the background changes to red, however, it stays red even after I log out. Anyway, is it possible to ask kindly for a screenshot of the error? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Changed the answer accordingly. You could have found out this for yourself if you'd read the docs I linked in my answer. Please accept it if it helped.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delay in checking your answer. I'm receiving this "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load." message from my main browser. Anyhow, where do I put the "FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', loginCallback);" and what's an onload handler?